# How to revover data from disc that has windows installed using live cd?

Tags: windows, data-recovery

Windows 10 in my pc stopped working so I booted into ubuntu 16.10 using live cd but I have some data in the drive I have windows 10 installed and I was wondering if I could recover that data.

I could access all the other discs but not the one which has windows, I mean I could see it but it doesn't show my data.

Comment: What happens if you try to mount the Windows partition?

Comment: @rlee827 I could see the disc partition, and it just shows some windows files in it but not all the files that I have.

Comment: What happens if you boot a Windows install/repair disc and try to repair your Windows?